# DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've ported an app I wrote in .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 4.7.2.

Basically almost everything was OK, a couple things were broken (as expected) but there is one thing that doesn't seem to be agnostic across netcore and .net.

And the line is:

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("test", SqlClientFactory.Instance);
var db = new Database("Server=TCPblablabla login", "test");

SqlSet <CharObj> products = db.From<CharObj>("[MyDb].[dbo].[Whatever]").Where("Name = {0}", myvar);
```

It works perfectly well on .netcore, however, it does not work on .Net 4.7.2. Because the DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory does not exist in 4.7.2.

I've seem a lot of people complaining about it, but I could not yet find any override etc. Do you guys have ANY idea on how to solve this issue?

[image: .Net 4.7.2 - Does not exist]

[image: .Netcore - Works like a charm!]

PS: It was not supposed to happen, I opened an issue on GitHub and they fixed it a couple of weeks after and closed my ticket, it was even shown in their C# news conference (I don't remember which).

Answer (score 2):

The way to switch providers in .Net Framework was with this line:

```
var dbProvider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.MySql")
```

Here are a couple of good links that show how to set up the DbProviderFactory the old way:

https://blog.codeinside.eu/2016/12/31/dbproviderfactory-write-database-agnostic-adonet-code/

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/nov/27/working-around-the-lack-of-dynamic-dbproviderfactory-loading-in-net-core

Hope this gets you on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

The `DbProviderFactories` class was designed a long time ago and registering factories must be done via the app configuration file on .NET Framework. The `RegisterFactory` method was only added later on .NET Core and never backported to .NET Framework.

But there exists a way to add a `DbProviderFactory` programmatically by tricking the configuration system on .NET Framework, see [Add a DbProviderFactory without an App.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117683/add-a-dbproviderfactory-without-an-app-config/1670950#1670950) to learn how to do it.