# How to use WebMatrix methods with Npgsql in .NET MVC Core 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, npgsql, .net-5, dbproviderfactories

I want to use WebMatrix.Data namespace

```
#region Assembly WebMatrix.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// .. \packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data.3.2.7\lib\net45\WebMatrix.Data.dll
```

with Npgsql data provider in ASP MVC Core 5.

In web.config it is defined as

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql"
  support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server"
  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

.NET 5 does not read config from web.config.
I tried according to

[Add a DbProviderFactory without an App.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117683/add-a-dbproviderfactory-without-an-app-config)

in code

```
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("NpgSql", Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
```

but got compile error RegisterFactory method does not exist. VS2019 assembly viewer confirms this:

```
#region Assembly System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Data.dll
#endregion

namespace System.Data.Common
{
    public static class DbProviderFactories
    {
        public static DbProviderFactory GetFactory(string providerInvariantName);
        public static DbProviderFactory GetFactory(DataRow providerRow);
        public static DbProviderFactory GetFactory(DbConnection connection);
        public static DataTable GetFactoryClasses();
    }
}
```

According to doc it must exist:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.registerfactory?view=net-5.0#System_Data_Common_DbProviderFactories_RegisterFactory_System_String_System_Data_Common_DbProviderFactory_

How to use Postgres database in WebMatrix in .NET MVC Core 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are targeting .NET Framework 4.8, not [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five):

> // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\**.NETFramework\v4.8**\System.Data.dll

Also, WebMatrix is an old technology which has been discontinued and whose formal [support has ended on November 1st, 2017](https://blogs.iis.net/webmatrix/webmatrix-product-support-ends-on-november-1st-2017). So it is unlikely that you will get it working on .NET 5.

Comment: My application is targeting to .NET 5. I have also other MVC, targeting to .NET 4.8. In this case it works. If called from .NET 5, Npgsql must registered from code to make it work in .NET 5.